# Grouping data with JavaScript (linq.js) with multiple grouping criteria?

Tags: javascript, linq.js

I've been reading stack overflow for some time now, and found that this time I have a question of my own to post as I can't quite find the answer. I'm quite new to Javascript and I'm having some difficulties getting started coming from a lot of work with SQL, Qlikview and VBA.

The question I have is about grouping a bunch of data in the way I would in SQL; from the research I've done it seems to me that **linq.js** is the way to go, or are there other good alternatives?

The data I have is following:

```
    var data = [

        { ID: I1, Group: G1, Name: A, ArrivalDate: 42097, ReturnDate: 42098, Travellers: 22, City: Boston },
        { ID: I1, Group: G1, Name: A, ArrivalDate: 42098, ReturnDate: 42099, Travellers: 22, City: New York },
        { ID: I1, Group: G1, Name: A, ArrivalDate: 42099, ReturnDate: 42100, Travellers: 22, City: Chicage },
        { ID: I2, Group: G1, Name: A, ArrivalDate: 42097, ReturnDate: 42098, Travellers: 14, City: Boston },
        { ID: I2, Group: G1, Name: A, ArrivalDate: 42098, ReturnDate: 42099, Travellers: 14, City: New York },
        { ID: I2, Group: G1, Name: A, ArrivalDate: 42099, ReturnDate: 42100, Travellers: 14, City: Chicage },
        { ID: I3, Group: G2, Name: B, ArrivalDate: 42091, ReturnDate: 42092, Travellers: 21, City: Boston },
        { ID: I3, Group: G2, Name: B, ArrivalDate: 42092, ReturnDate: 42093, Travellers: 21, City: New York },
        { ID: I3, Group: G2, Name: B, ArrivalDate: 42093, ReturnDate: 42094, Travellers: 21, City: Chicage },
        { ID: I4, Group: G2, Name: B, ArrivalDate: 42091, ReturnDate: 42092, Travellers: 22, City: Boston },
        { ID: I4, Group: G2, Name: B, ArrivalDate: 42092, ReturnDate: 42093, Travellers: 22, City: New York },
        { ID: I4, Group: G2, Name: B, ArrivalDate: 42093, ReturnDate: 42094, Travellers: 22, City: Chicage },
        { ID: I5, Group: G3, Name: C, ArrivalDate: 42082, ReturnDate: 42083, Travellers: 30, City: Boston },
        { ID: I5, Group: G3, Name: C, ArrivalDate: 42083, ReturnDate: 42084, Travellers: 30, City: New York },
        { ID: I5, Group: G3, Name: C, ArrivalDate: 42084, ReturnDate: 42085, Travellers: 30, City: Chicage },
        { ID: I6, Group: G3, Name: C, ArrivalDate: 42082, ReturnDate: 42083, Travellers: 10, City: Boston },
        { ID: I6, Group: G3, Name: C, ArrivalDate: 42083, ReturnDate: 42084, Travellers: 10, City: New York },
        { ID: I6, Group: G3, Name: C, ArrivalDate: 42084, ReturnDate: 42085, Travellers: 10, City: Chicage }
    ]
```

In SQL I would do following:

```
Select  ID,
        Group,
        Name, 
        min(ArrivalDate) as ArrivalDate, 
        max(ReturnDate) as ReturnDate, 
        Travellers
    from data
    group by ID, Group, Name, Travellers
```

The output would be:

```
    [
        { ID: I1, Group: G1, Name: A, ArrivalDate: 42097, ReturnDate: 42100, Travellers: 22 }
        { ID: I2, Group: G1, Name: A, ArrivalDate: 42097, ReturnDate: 42100, Travellers: 14 }
        { ID: I3, Group: G2, Name: B, ArrivalDate: 42091, ReturnDate: 42094, Travellers: 21 }
        { ID: I4, Group: G2, Name: B, ArrivalDate: 42091, ReturnDate: 42094, Travellers: 22 }
        { ID: I5, Group: G3, Name: C, ArrivalDate: 42082, ReturnDate: 42085, Travellers: 30 }
        { ID: I6, Group: G3, Name: C, ArrivalDate: 42082, ReturnDate: 42085, Travellers: 10 }
    ]
```

Intuitively this is what I would want to write with linq.js:

```
    var datagroup = Enumerable.From(data)
            .GroupBy("$.id", null,
                     function (key, g) {
                         return {
                           id: key,
                           group: g("$.group"),
                           name: g("$.name"),
                           arrivaldate: g.min("$.arrivaldate"),
                           returndate: g.max("$.returndate"),
                           travellers: g("$.travellers")
                         }
            })
            .ToArray();
```

Any help is a appreciated, thanks for being a great source of information!

Comment: also checkout https://lodash.com/docs which has a groupBy function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a composite key so you need to use the overloads that provide a compare function for the keys.

```
var query = Enumerable.From(data)
    .GroupBy(
        // key composed of ID, Group, Name, and Travellers
        "{ ID: $.ID, Group: $.Group, Name: $.Name, Travellers: $.Travellers }",
        null,
        "{ ID: $.ID, Group: $.Group, Name: $.Name, ArrivalDate: $$.Min('$.ArrivalDate'), ReturnDate: $$.Max('$.ReturnDate'), Travellers: $.Travellers }",
        // compare keys using this string representation
        "[ $.ID, $.Group, $.Name, $.Travellers ].join('|')")
    .ToArray();
```